# Using angular frontend in nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm a beginner with Node.JS and Angular and I want to create a project in the MEAN stack.

I have a backend in Node.JS and I want a frontend with angular. With gulp I do some preprocessing using Visual Studio Code.

When I start Node.JS and I want to my default view (index.html) I only get a 404 from Node.JS.

My project structure is as follows:

```
-api
   - config
   - controllers
   - models
   - services
   - app.js
-app
  - controllers
  - directives
  - libs
  - routes
  - scripts
  - services
  - views
  - app.js
-node_modules
   //All installed node_modules
-public
   //some static content
```

How can I tell node to look in the /app folder? Or how can I do this better? I did not have any code for adding a static folder, so I can't add that to my question.

Comment: You haven't included any of your code in the question. You need to supply a [mcve]. Where is the Express route that is supposed to serve index.html? Have you tried to write it? I get the impression that your current level of learning is at the "Needs to start with an introductory Express tutorial" level rather than having reached the type of specific problem that Stackoverflow is good for.

Comment: On a different note altogether , have you tried using the Sails JS platform ? Looking at your structure , I think Sails JS would suit you the best for this Project,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), where are the static files. You can include a folder or some static file.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

or

```
app.use(express.static(_dirname+'/public/index.html'))
```

**Edit 1:**
as @NVO suggested

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app')))
```

Comment: in case you want some external link http://thejackalofjavascript.com/developing-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-0/

Comment: Modified it a little bit, to app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app')));